# How to use author id in post permalink

Tags: permalinks

Currently, Wordpress supports author name in the post permalink by using %author%.

Is it possible to add the author id to the permalink?

For example, changing this:

http://www.site.com/john/my-first-post

to this:

http://www.site.com/1/my-first-post

Where '1' is the id of the author 'john'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a couple of filters:

```
<?php

function wpse_112719_pre_post_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    if ( strpos( $permalink, '%author%' ) !== false ) {
        $authordata = get_userdata( $post->post_author );
        $author_id = $authordata->ID;
        $permalink = str_replace( '%author%', $author_id, $permalink );
    }

    return $permalink;
}

add_filter( 'pre_post_link', 'wpse_112719_pre_post_link', 10, 3 );

function wpse_112730_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "([0-9]+)/(.*)",
        'index.php?name=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse_112730_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

Now, go to Settings → Permalinks and set your permalinks settings to `/%author%/%postname%/`. Save your changes, and your links should be working accordingly. Let me know if you have any issues!

Comment: Works great dude for rewrting the links! but it gives 404 error.

Comment: Good point. Working on a solution to that, but I may not have it for a day or so. It involves adding rewrite rules and parsing the URL accordingly.

Comment: I appreciate your support, and waiting for the new codes.

Comment: Just updated with brand new code - try it out (make sure to change your permalinks settings as described) and let me know how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Amazing! Works like a charm! Can't thank you enough man!

Comment: Can I make a redirection from old urls to new urls? for example, redirecting: (http://www.site.com/john/my-first-post) to (http://www.site.com/1/my-first-post)

Comment: Plus, pages don't work anymore, they redirect to the homepage.

Comment: Was able to fix this by replacing every %author_id% with %author%

Comment: Hey @Ahmed, are you all set now?

Comment: Instead of id, Can i use user firstname?