# Wordpress create permalink structure for custom post type with userid

Tags: plugins, php

I have a wordpress site I need to set url on the basis on userid like [www.mysite.com/customposttype/userid/postname](http://www.mysite.com/customposttype/userid/postname).
I have used Custom Post Types UI plugin for creating custom post. I tried many methods but not able to get exact url, please suggest some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to wpse! Have you checked the permalinks under settings?

Comment: yes, no option to add userid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use author id in post permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112719/how-to-use-author-id-in-post-permalink)

Answer (score -1):

From [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/112730/200755):

> You can do this with a couple of filters:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> function wpse_112719_pre_post_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
>     if ( strpos( $permalink, '%author%' ) !== false ) {
>         $authordata = get_userdata( $post->post_author );
>         $author_id = $authordata->ID;
>         $permalink = str_replace( '%author%', $author_id, $permalink );
>     }
>
>     return $permalink;
> }
>
> add_filter( 'pre_post_link', 'wpse_112719_pre_post_link', 10, 3 );
>
> function wpse_112730_add_rewrite_rules() {
>   add_rewrite_rule(
>       "([0-9]+)/(.*)",
>       'index.php?name=$matches[2]',
>       'top'
>   );
> }
>
> add_action( 'init', 'wpse_112730_add_rewrite_rules' );
> ```
>
> Now, go to Settings → Permalinks and set your permalinks settings
> to `/%author%/%postname%/`. Save your changes, and your links should
> be working accordingly. Let me know if you have any issues!